# How do I update an Environment Variable in a Visual Studio Deployment Project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I would like to append a path to the PATH environment variable in a Visual Studio 2005 deployment project.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use the registry editor view in the setup project and create the path key in the appropriate place 
ie.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
and create a string value called "Path"
and enter this as your value:
"[%Path];[TARGETDIR]"

[%Path] is a placeholder for the original string in the existing Path value.

Comment: This replaces and destroys the existing path

Comment: @MartinMurphy It actually doesn't destroy the path. This works quite well.

Comment: @MartinMurphy I had the same problem but when I rebuild the project , the problem goes away. I am using VS 2010.

Comment: As @Aaron Darling says in another comment. Uninstall removes the whole path variable instead of removing my adjustment !
So this solution is very useful but not complete !

Answer (score 4):

There are problems with the above mentioned approach of using the registry editor view and creating a key called PATH with value "[%Path];[TARGETDIR]".  While the method works fine when installing the program, the default behavior during uninstall is to delete the entire PATH variable, not just the added [TARGETDIR].  I have not found a way to disable this behavior, although it seems like some conditional behavior might be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a row to the Environment Table of the MSI file to do this.  You can find information on that table here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368369(VS.85).aspx.  You can use Orca to do this or automate the procedure with some VB Script.  The platform SDK contains the VB script file, WiRunSQL.vbs that can you used to automate build actions for your program.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to insert an entry in the environment table using a build action?

Comment: There is a link to some basic help information on the script file WiRunSQL.vbs here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368568(v=vs.85).aspx.  You need to download and install a copy of the Windows SDK to get the actual file.

Comment: Here are some blog posts describing the basic process of setting up an MSI post build event with Visual Studio 2005, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/24/716145.aspx and  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx

Comment: I was receiving error code 2356 when attempting to install the MSI edited by Orca even if I didn't make any changes and just saved as a different file.  This post solved that problem with a setting in Orca:  https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/nvvtbv/comment/h15gz7m/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3  `Tools -> Options -> Database -> Copy Embedded Streams during "Save As"` should be checked